# Uniqueness of decomposition into perfect set and scattered set

Tags: general-topology

In a topological space, a **dense-in-itself set** is a set without isolated point.  A **perfect set** is a closed dense-in-itself set.  A **scattered set** is a set that contains no nonempty dense-in-itself subset.

Given a space $X$, the union of a family of dense-in-itself sets is dense-in-itself, and the closure of a dense-in-itself set is dense-in-itself, and hence perfect.  So by taking the union of all dense-in-itself subsets of $X$, one gets a perfect set $P$.  And the complement of $P$ does not contain any nonempty dense-in-itself subset; so it is scattered.  This proves:

> **Theorem:** Every topological space can be decomposed into the disjoint union of a perfect set and a scattered set.

How can you show this decomposition is unique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider any decomposition of $X$ into a perfect set $Q$ and a scattered set $U=X\setminus Q$; we wish to show that $Q$ is equal to your $P$.  Trivially $Q\subseteq P$. To show $P\subseteq Q$, it suffices to show that if $A\subseteq X$ is dense-in-itself, then $A\subseteq Q$.  Now note that since $U$ is open, if $A$ is dense-in-itself then so is $A\cap U$.  But since $U$ is scattered, this means $A\cap U=\emptyset$, i.e. $A\subseteq Q$, as desired.